# Get picklist value LABEL in formula field

Tags: formula-field, platform-bug

My question can sound trivial, but the issue below seems to be serious.
We can use `TEXT(field)` to get picklist value in formula field.

The issue is that this method returns **API name** of particular value and not label.

Does anybody know if we can obtain **Label** of picklist value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use formula to convert API name back to label with case statement.

```
CASE(TEXT(field),
  "API 1", "Label 1",
  "API 2", "Label 2",
  "Error"
)
```

PS: you will need to update your formula whenever you updates pick list values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Nevertheless, this is work around. It would be great to have function that can differ between label and api name.

Comment: Works, real PIA when the picklist is huge.  There is a character limit on formula field (3900 characters?)  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385147&type=1